# Dojo Charting Tooltip not visible

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am trying to create a chart with custom tool tip. You can see the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AnandVishnu/feW6x/) example here.

I have added a custom tooltip which does not appear. I can see the event fires(with the help of console.log) but the tooltip somehow does not appear(as if the rendering is not not happening) :(

```
 var tip = new Tooltip(c, "default", {
            text: function (o) {
                console.log(o);
                return (o.y);
            }
        });
```

Any hint to help me going ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just the case of missing CSS for the tooltip. I added the link to

```
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css
```

and it worked fine. Thanks